# What could be causing this exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, arraylist

I'm occasionally getting a very strange exception:

> 04-18 18:08:08.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3031): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   04-18 18:08:08.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3031): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   04-18 18:08:08.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3031):     at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:257)
>   04-18 18:08:08.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3031):     at com.zigzagworld.text.formatter.FormatManager.formatIfNeeded(FormatManager.java:185)
>   etc.

This is happening on a 1.6 emulator. The line in my code that calls `addAll` is:

```
mTasksAbove.addAll(schedule.above);
```

The only thing I can imagine is some sort of concurrent access to `mTasksAbove`. However, I've been very careful to ensure that all accesses are synchronized on the same object. The only other thing I thought of was if `schedule.above` were modified during execution of `addAll`, but I believe that would generate a `ConcurrentModificationException` (plus, I don't think my code does that). Does anyone know of anything else I should be looking for?

**EDIT**

Based on Raykud's answer, I did a little digging and found the exact bug. In the Android 1.6 sources, the `addAll` method calls an internal method, `growAtEnd` that is buggy. Here's the source itself:

```
private void growAtEnd(int required) {
    int size = size();
    if (firstIndex >= required - (array.length - lastIndex)) {
        int newLast = lastIndex - firstIndex;
        if (size > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(array, firstIndex, array, 0, size);
            int start = newLast < firstIndex ? firstIndex : newLast;
            Arrays.fill(array, start, array.length, null);
        }
        firstIndex = 0;
        lastIndex = newLast;
    } else {
        int increment = size / 2;
        if (required > increment) {
            increment = required;
        }
        if (increment < 12) {
            increment = 12;
        }
        E[] newArray = newElementArray(size + increment);
        if (size > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(array, firstIndex, newArray, 0, size);
            /********************************************************\
            * BUG! The next 2 lines of code should be outside the if *
            \********************************************************/
            firstIndex = 0;
            lastIndex = size;
        }
        array = newArray;
    }
}
```

The bug rears its ugly head when the list had been previously populated and then emptied, leaving `size == 0` and `firstIndex == lastIndex > 0` and you try to add a collection large enough that it doesn't fit between `lastIndex` and the current array size.

The bug is gone as of 2.2, when the `addAll` method was rewritten and `growAtEnd` disappeared from the class.

Thanks, Raykud, for the pointer!

Comment: What kind of is `schedule.above`?

Comment: I also think it's a synchronization issue - the source code for ArrayList.addAll() seems benign, if anything, the System.arraycopy() is what's throwing the exception. Can you print out the size of schedule.above and the current size and capacity of mTasksAbove before each call?

Comment: Actually, you say that you synchronize mTasksAbove meticulously. What about schedule.above? Could that change while you're adding it?

Comment: @steveoh - `schedule.above` is also an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @EboMike - I don't synchronize access to `schedule.above`, but `schedule` is returned from one method and passed to the code that calls `addAll`. No other code has access to it. Plus, wouldn't changes cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` by the iterator in `addAll`? I'll look into printing out list sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of 1.5 the method addAll in arraylist was buggy, it was supposed to get fixed in a future realease, however I'm not sure in wich one.
To work around this you could create an [Iterator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) for your collection and adding the elements one by one.
Here is a little code to help:

```
Iterator<MyTypeofObjectToAdd> e = myArrayListToCopyFrom.iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
      arrayListToAdd(e.next());
    }
```

and the [IndexOutOfBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) exception is caused because you are trying to retrieve an item from a position where there is nothing.

Comment: Thanks for this info. It's disturbing that `addAll` is buggy. However, this doesn't seem quite like my issue -- null elements won't cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception (which is happening during the call to `addAll`, not when I'm calling `get()`). I'll try your approach and see whether the problem goes away.

Comment: I've confirmed that there is a bug. It seems to have gone away as of Android 2.2 (API level 8). Thanks again!